# If $x>0$, $\,x^{1/n}$ tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am looking for a proof possibly using the sandwich theorem and/or Bernoulli's inequality for proving the following statement:

If $x>0$ then $x^{1/n}$ tends to $1$.

Comment: Are you looking exclusively for sandwich and/or bernoulli?

Comment: Yes please, if it is possible with them, these are the tools I have the best experience with and that form will be the most useful to me.

Comment: What about $n$? Does it tends to infinity?

Comment: For the upper bound you can use $x^{1/n} < 1+\frac{x}{n}$ since (Bernoulli) $(1+x)^a > 1+ax$.

Comment: stefan4024 yes n is the natural numbers and tends to infinity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $x>1$. Then, let $x^{1/n}=1+h_n$.

We will show that $h_n \rightarrow 0$. $x=(1+h_n)^n \geq 1+nh_n$. Then, $0 \leq h_n \leq (x-1)/n \rightarrow 0$. Thus the result follows by Sandwich theorem.

For $0<x<1$, just consider $\dfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: what is h_n in this? just the remainder of x^{1/n}-1?

Comment: @JackWightman: yes. Notice that $x^{1/n}$ has to be greater than $1$ as $x>1$. (If $x^{1/n}=a<1$, then $a^n<1$, which means $x<1$)

Comment: one last thing, what do you mean by consider 1/x for 0<x<1?

Comment: @JackWightman: If $x<1$, the $y=1/x$ is greater than $1$. Now, the proof above shows that $y^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$. But, $y^{1/n}=1/x^{1/n}$, which means that $x^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: thanks so much think I've got this now, really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

An argument avoiding Bernoulli's inequality: Suppose first that $ x\ge1$. It suffices to prove that $ n^{1/n}\to1$, since $ x <n $ if $ n $ is large enough. For this, just check that $ n <(1+\sqrt {2/n})^n $, by directly expanding the right hand side.

Finally, if $0 <x <1$, apply the above to conclude that $(1/x)^{1/n}\to1$, and the result follows by considering inverses.