# Limit of a function using epsilon delta

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to prove that, for some constant $x_0$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{(x-x_0)^{\frac 1 n}} \to 1$$

where I verified the result above with Wolfram Alpha.

I am struggling in the epsilon delta though. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. The problem is that $n \to \infty$ so I'm not sure if I should be doing $|n - \infty| < \delta \implies \left|\frac{1}{(x-x_0)^{\frac 1 n}} - 1\right| < \varepsilon$ or how that $|n - \infty|$ is defined. How should I proceed?

Comment: The definition is $\forall \varepsilon > 0,  \exists N$ such that $\forall n > N, \left|\frac{1}{(x-x_0)^{\frac 1 n}} - 1\right| < \varepsilon$. There's no need for deltas here as we're talking about pointwise convergence.

Comment: @Robbie would it be correct to say that the $lim_{n \to \infty}$ notation here implies we want to use the pointwise definition?

Comment: The reason I assumed this was pointwise convergence was that the RHS is a constant, not a function. This makes it seem like we're talking about one value of $x$ at a time. There's no standard though – if you want to talk about uniform convergence, you should say so, and if not, you should say $x>x_0$, pointwise.

Comment: I should also clarify – the reason we don't need any $\delta$s here is that there's no notion of "if these two points are close enough, then..." here. This isn't a question of continuity, for example.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. Yes the $x$ is a constant, I fix the $x$ elsewhere in the proof. But I am kind of struggling to find the $N$ now, in particular, I am trying to isolate the $n$ in the $|1/... - 1| < \varepsilon$ section but can't seem to do it

Comment: Ok. The convergence of this particular sequence has already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000511/if-x0-x1-n-tends-to-1-as-n-to-infty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof but rather a standard sequence convergence proof. Further, the limit exists for all $x>x_0$ so I'm not sure why that is part of the question. What you are really trying to prove is that for any positive number $a$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}=1$$

There are many ways to prove this but I prefer this way: We have that

$$a^{1/n}=e^{\ln(a^{1/n})}=e^{\frac{\ln(a)}{n}}$$

Since $\ln(a)$ is a real number and $e^x$ is continuous at $x=0$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\ln(a)}{n}}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(a)}{n}}=e^0=1$$

Of course, this proof might not suffice for you depending on what you have already proved but its a good start nonetheless.