# Radius of convergence with factorials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to apply Cauchy-Hadamard to find the ratio of convergence of the following.

1. $\sum \frac{n^4}{n!}x^n$. For this one, I figured that the $\limsup$ should be 0 since the factorial dominates, and thus the interior is $0$ and $n$th root of $0$ is just $0$. Thus the radius is $\infty$. However, this answer suggests that we should go to 1: [If $x>0$, $\,x^{1/n}$ tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000511/if-x0-x1-n-tends-to-1-as-n-to-infty) - why can I not apply that answer?
2. $\sum n^2 2^nx^n$ - not sure how to start with this one. Graphically, it goes to $2$, although I'm not sure why again. I think I am misunderstanding when I can apply that answer above.

Comment: (Note that it's "radius of convergence" rather than "ratio of convergence".) Remember that you're looking for the limit of the $n$th root of $|\frac{n^4}{n!}x^n|$, not the limit of the $n$th root of $x$.

Comment: @GregMartin I thought we only need to find the $n$th root of $|\frac{n^4}{n!}|$, not including the $x^n$? Also if we let $ a = |\frac{n^4}{n!}|$, then $a > 0$ and I thought i could apply the linked answer to see it tends to $1$.

Comment: It can be phrased either way; I was trying to guess what way you were doing it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use that $n^{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$ and $n!^{\frac{1}{n}} \to \infty$.

Then 1. is $\infty$ and 2. is $\frac{1}{2}$.